# How to delete an element from a jQuery object? And how to output as HTML in Firefox scratchpad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script, which I have adapted from this helpful source: https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/596146

I have this working in the browser with no problems, after a little adaptation for my purposes. However, when testing, I realised that there was the possibility that when cloning the table row there could be a Django/Bootstrap error message in the row, that I did not want to be in the newly inserted row.

The problem being that the error message is inserted with the new row, which should not happen, because it is not relevant to the new row.

This snippet now has the solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en">

    <head>
    
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <title>Edit register</title>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
            .invalid-feedback {
                background: pink;
                }
                
        </style>
        
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <h3>Add to register</h3>
        
        <form method=POST>
        
        <table width="100%" cellspacing=20 cellpadding=5 border=0 class="spaced-row" id="member-rows">
        
            <tr valign="top" class="float-th">
                <th><small>Members</small></th><th><small>Present</small></th><!--<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>--><th><small>Late</small></th>
                
            </tr>
            
            
            <tr valign="top" class="spaced-row  hide-check-label new-form-container">
                    
                <input type="hidden" name="member_register_set-23-id" id="id_member_register_set-23-id">
                
                <td>
                
                    <label for="id_member_register_set-23-key_entry">Add member</label>
                    
                    <div class="add_member_list_class">
                                    
                        <input type="text" name="member_register_set-23-key_entry" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Click field and press space bar to get choices" title="Type a few characters and select from the pop-up menu" id="id_member_register_set-23-key_entry" size=50>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">You have ticked the Present or Late boxes without entering a valid member name.  Enter a valid member name, or untick the box(es).</div>
                    
                    <small>Type a few characters and select from the pop-up menu</small>
                                        
                    <input type="hidden" name="member_register_set-23-member" id="id_member_register_set-23-member">
                                        
                </td>
                
                <td align="center">
                                                            
                    <input type="checkbox" name="member_register_set-23-present" class="form-check-input is-valid" id="id_member_register_set-23-present" checked>
                    
                    <label  for="id_member_register_set-23-present">Present</label>
                    
                </td>
                
                <td align="center">                 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="member_register_set-23-late" class="form-check-input is-valid" id="id_member_register_set-23-late">
                                
                    <label for="id_member_register_set-23-late">Late</label>
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="member_register_set-23-register" value="n6KS2X5bKgpMtGpsKwt2wB" id="id_member_register_set-23-register">
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="member_register_set-23-id" id="id_member_register_set-23-id">
                    
                </td>
                
            </tr>
                    
                                
                                
        </table>
            
            
            <button type="submit">Does nothing - do not click</button>
            
            </form>
            
            
            
            
    
            
            
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        
            //add_member_list_class

            $(document).on('keydown', '.add_member_list_class .form-control', function() {
            
                
                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split('-');
                var index = splitid[1];
                
                var listdata = [
                                    {"result": 1, "label": "choose me", "value": "a"},
                                    {"result": 1, "label": "or me", "value": "b"},
                                    {"result": 0, "label": "do not choose me", "value": "c"},
                                ]
                            ;

                $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                    
                    source: listdata ,

                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        
                        if (ui.item.result != 0) {

                            document.getElementById('id_member_register_set-'+index+'-key_entry').value = ui.item.label;
                            document.getElementById('id_member_register_set-'+index+'-member').value = ui.item.value;
                            
                            
                            /* - trying insert row on select - */
                    
                            // create a clone of the existing form elements, but with blank fields.
                            $('tr.new-form-container:last').clone().each(function(i) {
                                $(this).find('input,select').each(function(i) {
                                            
                                    // update the id attributes, incrementing the form number, e.g.: "id_form-1-field_name"
                                    parts = $(this).attr('id').split('-', 3); 
                                    num = parseInt(parts[1]) + 1;
                                    $(this).attr('id', parts[0] + '-' +num + '-' +parts[2]);
                    
                                    // Update the name attribute, e.g.: form-1-field_name
                                    parts = $(this).attr('name').split('-', 3); 
                                    num = parseInt(parts[1])  + 1; 
                                    $(this).attr('name', parts[0] + '-' +num + '-' +parts[2]);
                
                                    // Remove any existing values 
                                    if($(this).attr('id') == ('id_member_register_set-' + num + '-register')) {
                                        //alert('that is the register element: ' + num + ' - ' + $(this).attr('value'));
                                        // don't set the  value to empty if it is the register ID
                                        }
                                    else if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                                        //alert('input is checkbox');
                                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                                        }
                                    else {
                                        $(this).val('');
                                        }
                                        ;
                                    
                
                                }); 
                                    
                                // Update the "for" attribute for all labels 
                                $(this).find('label').each(function(i) {
                                    parts = $(this).attr('for').split('-', 3); 
                                    num = parseInt(parts[1]) + 1;
                                    $(this).attr('for', parts[0] + '-' +num + '-' +parts[2]);
                                });
                                
                                // remove existing errors if adding row
                                //$(this).removeClass('.invalid-feedback');
                                
                                
                                
                                //$('.invalid-feedback').remove(); //removes from last input, but not new

                                
                                $(this).find('.invalid-feedback').remove();
                                
                                
                                
                    
                            }).appendTo('table#member-rows');
                                
                            // Increment the TOTAL_FORMS
                            $('#id_member_register_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt($('#id_member_register_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val()) + 1); 
                            
                            /* - ending insert row on select - */
                                                        
                            }
                        
                        else {
                        
                            alert('That is not a valid choice');
                            $( ("#id_member_register_set-" + index + "-key_entry") ).val( '' );
                            
                            

                        }
                        
                        
                        return false;
                        
                    },
                    
                //minLength: 3

                
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</body></html>
```

After reviewing @jerry’s post I found the crucial line was:

```
$(this).find('.invalid-feedback').remove();
```

Which is now in the above snippet.

In addition, I figured out how to work through this in the Firefox scratchpad, in particular how to output the jQuery object into the console rendered as HTML so that I can check it.

```
var o = $('tr.new-form-container:last').clone();
o.find('.invalid-feedback').remove();
//my way
console.log(o[0].outerHTML);
//@jerry’s way, which is cleaner/more readable
console.log(o.html());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't attach the original html so I create a simple version of removing element based on your class name.

```js
function removeInvalidFeedbackDirect(){
  $(".invalid-feedback").remove()
}

function removeInvalidFeedbackRelative(){
  $("#wrapper").find(".invalid-feedback").remove()
}

function printHtmlInConsole(){
  let html = $("#wrapper").html()
  console.log(html)
}

let index = 2 //set to 2 because already exist 2 in html
function insertNewInvalidRow(){
  index++
  let html = $(`<div class="invalid-feedback" data-id="${index}">invalid feedback #${index} with same class <button type="button" class="removeBtn">remove this row only</button></div>`)
  html.find(".removeBtn").on("click",function(e){
    //.closest() find to the nearest parent element that match the given css selector
    $(this).closest(".invalid-feedback").remove()
  })
  html.appendTo("#wrapper")
}

function deleteByRowIndex(){
  let targetId = $("#deleteTarget").val()
  if(targetId){
    $(`.invalid-feedback[data-id='${targetId}']`).remove()
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="invalid-feedback" data-id="1">invalid feedback #1 with same class</div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" data-id="2">invalid feedback #2 with same class</div>
</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="insertNewInvalidRow
()">Add new Row with remove button</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="removeInvalidFeedbackDirect
()">Remove all by using direct css selector</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="removeInvalidFeedbackRelative
()">Remove all by using relative css selector</button><br>
<input type="text" id="deleteTarget"><button type="button" onclick="deleteByRowIndex
()">Remove row by index</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="printHtmlInConsole
()">print html in console</button><br>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit #1

1. Added new scenario to delete the element by using `.closest()`. It find to the nearest parent element that match the given css selector
2. Added new scenario to delete the dynamically appended element by using index.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain the problem properly, I need to delete the ```<div class="invalid-feedback">``` from the inserted row, not all instances. See my new snippet.

Comment: As above, after reviewing your post, I worked out the missing line was ```$(this).find('.invalid-feedback').remove();```. I could not get the other ```.remove()``` method to work. The ```object.html()``` output worked too.

Comment: @typonaut edited my post to give you more option to delete row selectively. The reason your `remove()` don't work it could due to the `$(this)` selected element is not what you expecting, you can try to do `console.log(this)` to see what element it selected.